# How do I delete header rows out of my data frame in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

In my data huge .csv dataframe, I have merged 100+ csvs through cmd. This includes the headers. Now, I wish to delete the following duplicated header from my master csv in R:

```
Year|RecID|ParID|ConParID|Country|Division|RegCnty|RegDist|SubDist|RC|RD|RSD|Parish|Area|Part|Population|MalePop|FemalePop|NoOfInstit|InstitPop|ParType|Censusref|ImageRef|PageType|DocType|EnuDist|BuildType|BTCode|NoOfRooms|NoOfRoomsCode|Schedule|H|Absent|Absentcode|HSS|InstName|InstDesc|VessName|VessPos|PID|Sex|SexInf|Age|Cage|AgeInf|Cond|Mar|MarInf|Relat|Rela|RelInf|HeadInf|Occ|HollerOcc|Occode|HISCO|Industry|HollerInd|Employ|EmployCode|AtHome|Inactive|Disab|DisCode1|DisCode2|Bpstring|BpCmty|Std_Par|BpCnty|Cnti|Alt_Cnti|BpCtry|Ctry|Alt_Ctry|HollerB|Nationality|Lang|Langcode|YearsMar|MarYear|ChildTot|ChildAlive|ChildDead|ChildrenCode|HHD|H_Sex|H_Age|H_Rela|H_Mar|H_Occ|H_CFU|SameName|CFU|n_CFUs|tn_CFUs|CFUsize|Spouse|Father|Mother|f_Off|m_Off|m_Offm|f_Offm|Offsp|Kids|Relats|Inmates|Servts|Non_Rels|Visitors|Military
```

This header appears as many times as there were initial csv files, and not at a regular interval. How can I select all rows containing this header to include it in the following code:

```
myData <- myData[-c(...)]
```

Any help appreciated or other alternative solutions. It's big data, so I cannot open and remove duplicates in excel.

Comment: Better to not read them in in the first place.  `read.csv` has the `header` argument, for example.  Details in the online doc.

Comment: I have hundreds of files, with names such as 8721dnis843284, this would take an incredible amount of time and diligence to compile.... I'll look into it though. But I think the approach I have taken has the easiest solution...

Comment: Do you still have those 100+ csv? Instead of merging them using cmd, do it all in R, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/680068

Comment: Get the file names in a list.  `list.files`?  Then `bind_rows(lapply, fileList, read.csv, header=TRUE)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging them in `cmd` it is advised to do so in R, as merging all data (UNION) along with header as rows, will result in changing the column type to strings everywhere and you'll have to do a lot of work to change their types all over again.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/2884859) answer for complete help as to how merge these in R itself.

If still you have a merged data that you don't want to repeat the steps all over again, you can remove the header rows in R by this command.

Obviously Year column won't have value `Year` except in header rows so do this

```
myData <- myData[myData$Year != 'Year',]
```

`myData$Year != 'Year'` will have `True` for only meaningful rows and replace `myData` with subset of these meaninful i.e. (non-header) rows only.

If you have Year column values equal to 'Year' anywhere use this logic on some other column

Comment: This would work, but then you end up with a dataframe with all columns class of character. Better read all in a loop and let R convert to suitable classes, then rowbind.

Comment: But, if OP has already an UNION of data in such a way that header rows are repeated across the data and still don't want to do it all over again, then it is sure that all columns are of character type only

Comment: Exactly, since all in character, with this answer we are creating another problem to solve: convert all noncharacter to specific classes. Better avoid that step, and let R do it automagically when importing each file separately, then simply rowbind.

Comment: agree it with fully

Comment: Thank you guys. Can someone sum up the approach I should be taking?

Comment: @RyeRye Please see the linked posts.